# Visual studio build events, check git branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way for the build events, in VS, to check which git branch is checked out.
I only want certain events to trigger, when in the master branch.
Thanks

Comment: How about creating a batch file that is different in the different branches, and just calling that batch file from the build events.

Comment: Hi this would work thanks. My only issue then is how do I, in git, have two files that are not equal, when using a normal merge strategy,
How do I make the file not being the same in master and develop, when I merge develop into master?

Comment: The problem comes if you both merge develop into master and master into develop, then you're going to have issues. With a git-flow workflow, you might be able to avoid it. Let's say you first create the batch file on your develop branch, suited *for* the develop branch. Then you merge those commits onto the master branch. Then, on the master branch, fix the batch file so it is suited for the master branch. Unless you touch the very same lines in the develop branch, a merge from develop into master will bring with it **further changes**, not the whole file.